# R plotly::save_image / kaleido : static export from R not working

Tags: plotly, export, reticulate, save-image, kaleido

I am trying to save a static image from a plotly graph using plotly::save_image(), but everytime I run this function, Rstudio gets stack (busy red icon) and needs to be restarted. There is not any error message displayed.

I have run the following commands and they all seem to have been installed correctly:

**install.packages('reticulate') 

reticulate::install_miniconda()  

reticulate::conda_install('r-reticulate', 'python-kaleido') 

reticulate::conda_install('r-reticulate', 'plotly', channel = 'plotly') 

reticulate::use_miniconda('r-reticulate')**

RStudio gets stack in a busy (red circle) state when save_image(p, tmp) is run:

**p <- plot_ly(x = 1:10)  

save_image(p, "test.png")**

Thank you for your help

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 

 Additional information including sessionInfo() output:

System type : 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

 Edition     : Windows 10 Enterprise

 version     : 21H2

 Installed on: 29/‎04/‎2022


 plotly version     : 4.10.0

 reticulate version : 1.24

R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22 ucrt)

 Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

 Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)


 Matrix products: default


 locale:

 LC_COLLATE=English_New Zealand.utf8  
 LC_CTYPE=English_New Zealand.utf8

 LC_MONETARY=English_New Zealand.utf8 
 LC_NUMERIC=C

 LC_TIME=English_New Zealand.utf8


 attached base packages:

 stats  
    graphics 
  grDevices 
  utils  
    datasets 
  methods  
  base


 other attached packages:

 plotly_4.10.0 
  ggplot2_3.3.5


 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):

 pillar_1.7.0    
   compiler_4.2.0 
    tools_4.2.0     
   digest_0.6.29     
 viridisLite_0.4.0 
 jsonlite_1.8.0  
   evaluate_0.15   
   lifecycle_1.0.1  
  tibble_3.1.6   
    gtable_0.3.0    
 pkgconfig_2.0.3  
  rlang_1.0.2   
     cli_3.3.0     
     DBI_1.1.2 
         yaml_2.3.5      
 xfun_0.30     
     fastmap_1.1.0  
    httr_1.4.2  
       withr_2.5.0   
     dplyr_1.0.8  
 knitr_1.39   
      generics_0.1.2  
   vctrs_0.4.1   
     htmlwidgets_1.5.4  
 grid_4.2.0      
 tidyselect_1.1.2 
  glue_1.6.2    
     data.table_1.14.2 R6_2.5.1   
        fansi_1.0.3      
 rmarkdown_2.14  
   bookdown_0.26   
   tidyr_1.2.0     
   purrr_0.3.4   
     magrittr_2.0.3   
 scales_1.2.0   
    ellipsis_0.3.2   
  htmltools_0.5.2 
   assertthat_0.2.1  
 colorspace_2.0-3 
 utf8_1.2.2   
      lazyeval_0.2.2  
   munsell_0.5.0   
   crayon_1.5.1

Comment: Hi - Did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this still helps, I think I found the solution. Apparently in windows 10 and 11, you need an older version of kaleido.
To get it, instead of: `reticulate::conda_install('r-reticulate', 'python-kaleido')`
try `reticulate::conda_install('r-reticulate', 'python-kaleido==0.1.*')`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add this line in your code:

```
reticulate::py_run_string("import sys")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.